# "Extract" a branch from commits made under a directory

Tags: git

Is there a way in git to create a branch with only the commits that affected a directory?

For example, given a repo like the following (commit, commit's patch, branch):

```
g  dir3/file33 (develop)
f  dir1/file12
e  dir2/file22
d  dir2/file21
c  dir1/file11
b  dir3/file32 (master)
a  dir3/file31
```

Create a branch that looks like:

```
f' dir1/file12 (feature dir1)
c  dir1/file11
b  dir3/file32 (master)
a  dir3/file31
```

So far I've thought of doing something like:

```
git log --right-only --cherry-pick master...develop -- dir1
```

I think this returns the commits that I need on the new branch, but I don't know how to "extract" a branch with these commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git subtree split` is what you need.

Since some version of Git it's available right away; in older versions it was a script in the "contrib" directory of the Git distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Do a git filter branch on your branch. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch for full details. Look at the --subdirectory-filter  flag. I was just rereading your problem statement and it looks like you want to filter multiple directories and not just one? If so, it looks like --subdirectory-filter can't be used since you can only specify one directory with it (and it doesn't look like you can specify --subdirectory-filter multiple times, once for each different directory).

Also look at https://github.com/slobobaby/git_filter

Comment: It looks like he just wants 'dir1' (his branch starts at 'master' in the example given) so I think --subdirectory-filter will work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps patching is better suited to your needs.

create patch with the following command:

```
git diff origin/master HEAD -- <pathToDirectory>/ > changes.patch
```

Then make your branch however you plan to, hopefully from a commit which is a common ancestor, and apply the patch.
Here are the official docs for [diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and [applying](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) a patch. With this way, if there are conflicts you can easily resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting commits for the changes they made, you want rebase or cherrypick.  For this, it looks like cherrypick's going to be easiest.

```
git checkout -b feature/dir1 master
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse master..develop -- dir1)
```

is the easy way to do it, it won't notice that it could just fast-forward over your commit `c` but does that really matter?  If it does, just swap `c`'s id in for `master` in the above, but remember to undo that when you go back for the other directory(ies).